# KDB/Q: multiple PEACH?

Tags: kdb

I have a function that takes 2 parameters: date and sym. I would like to do this for multiple dates and multiple sym. I have a list for each parameter. I can currently loop through 1 list using

```
raze function[2020.07.07;] peach symlist
```

How can I do something similar but looping through the list of dates too?

Answer (score 2):

You may try following:

1. Create list of pairs of input parameters.
2. Write anonymous function which calls your `function` and use `peach`on list op paired parameters

For example

```
symlist: `A`B`C; // symlist defined for testing
function: {(x;y)}; // function defined for testing
raze {function . x} peach (2020.07.07 2020.07.08 2020.07.09) cross symlist
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
raze function'[2020.07.07 2020.07.08 2020.07.09;] peach symlist
```

If not some more things to consider. Could you change your function to accept a sym list instead of individual syms by including an each/peach inside it? Then you could each the dates.

Also, you could create a new list of each date matched with the symlist and create a new function which takes this list and does whatever the initial function did by separating the elements of the list.

```
q)dates
2020.08.31 2020.09.01 2020.09.02
q)sym
`llme`obpb`dhca`mhod`mgpg`jokg`kgnd`nhke`oofi`fnca`jffe`hjca`mdmc
q)func
{[date;syms]string[date],/:string peach syms}
q)func2
{[list]func[list 0;list 1]}
q)\t res1:func[;sym]each dates
220
q)\t res2:func[;sym]peach dates
102
q)
q)func2
{[list]func[list 0;list 1]}
q)dateSymList:dates,\:enlist sym
q)\t res3:func2 peach dateSymList
80
q)res3~res2
1b
q)res3~res1
1b
```

Let us know if any of those solutions work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible ways to do this

Can project dyadic f as monadic & parallelise over list of argument pairs

```
q)a:"ABC";b:til 3;f:{(x;y)}
q)\s 4
q)(f .)peach l:raze a,\:/:b
"A" 0
"B" 0
"C" 0
"A" 1
"B" 1
"C" 1
"A" 2
"B" 2
"C" 2
```

Or could define function to take a dictionary argument & parallelise over a table

```
q)f:{x`c1`c2}
q)f peach flip`c1`c2!flip l
"A" 0
"B" 0
"C" 0
"A" 1
"B" 1
"C" 1
"A" 2
"B" 2
"C" 2
```

Jason

Answer (score 0):

I'll generalize everything, if you have a given function foo which will operate on an atom `dt` with a vector `s`

```
q)foo:{[dt;s] dt +\: s}
q)dt:10?10
q)s:100?10
q)dt
8 1 9 5 4 6 6 1 8 5
q)s
4 9 2 7 0 1 9 2 1 8 8 1 7 2 4 5 4 2 7 8 5 6 4 1 3 3 7 8 2 1 4 2 8 0 5 8 5 2 8..
q)foo[;s] each dt
12 17 10 15 8 9  17 10 9  16 16 9  15 10 12 13 12 10 15 16 13 14 12 9  11 11 ..
5  10 3  8  1 2  10 3  2  9  9  2  8  3  5  6  5  3  8  9  6  7  5  2  4  4  ..
13 18 11 16 9 10 18 11 10 17 17 10 16 11 13 14 13 11 16 17 14 15 13 10 12 12 ..
9  14 7  12 5 6  14 7  6  13 13 6  12 7  9  10 9  7  12 13 10 11 9  6  8  8  ..
```

The solution is to project the symList over the function in question, then use `each` (or `peach`) for the `date` variable.

If your function requires an atomic date and sym, then you can just create a new function to implement this

```
q)bar:{[x;y] foo[x;] each y};
```

Answer (score -4):

```
datelist:`date$10?10
symlist:10?`IBM`MSFT`GOOG
function:{0N!(x;y)}

{.[function;x]} each datelist cross symlist
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.